# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\dd\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 305

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this code to get the HMO and PHIC amount of every patient. My problem is whenever I try to get 50+ records of patients, it always show a fatal error. Can someone help me. Thank you!

```
$this->db->select("pxtype,(casecode) as casecodex,patientname,concat(dischadate,' ',dischatime) as discha , 

        (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where hospcode NOT LIKE 'MI%' and hospcode NOT LIKE 'PD%' and hospcode NOT LIKE 'PF%' and casecode = casecodex) as ACTUALHOSP,
        (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where hospcode LIKE 'PDPP%' and casecode = casecodex ) as PHICHOSP,
        (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where hospcode LIKE 'MI%' and hospcode NOT LIKE 'MIMD%' and casecode = casecodex) as HMOHOSP,
        (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where hospcode LIKE 'PFMD%' and casecode = casecodex) as ACTUALPF,
        (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where hospcode LIKE 'PD%' and hospcode NOT LIKE 'PDPP%' and casecode = casecodex) as PHICPF,
        (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where hospcode LIKE 'MIMD%' and casecode = casecodex) as HMOPF")
            ->from(inpatient_ipd_vw)
            ->where('dischadate >= "'.$first.'"')
            ->where('dischadate <= "'.$end.'"')
             ->where("hospcode LIKE 'MI%'");

             if($hmocode !== NULL && $hmocode !== "All" )
             {
                 $this->db->where('hmocode',$hmocode);
             }
             $this->db->group_by('casecode' );
```

Comment: Your query is taking too long to execute; probably due to all the *like* and  *not like* statements. You should optimize your query or accept that it will take long and you have to increase `max_execution_time`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can optimize my query? Thank you!

Comment: what are your table indexes? your whole db structure could probably be improved, be we dont have enough information to say how

Comment: their might be, but at the end of the day it sounds like a database schema issue that stems from improper development and without knowing what is what or why this was chosen over that its almost impossible for us to say. for example, why do you need a statement `LIKE PFMD%` can't you just do a where PFMD? or is it not always entered into the database like that? because if its not, it should be. standardized inputs allow you to query the database properly and without likes. likes should only be used when abs necessary, like searches for a customer name for example.

Comment: Hi! I need to use like because there are other letters after PFMD. So I need to search everything that begins with PFMD.

Comment: Like PFMD61191, PFMD61013.. So it's really necessary for me to use like.

Comment: I have a field name: hospcode. In there, I have multiple entries that starts with MI, PDPP, PFMD and MIMD.

Comment: @AlynnaPajaron use [**Benchmarking Class**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html) to profile how long query takes to execute. *Note: for this alow maximum memory for temporarily. if its more then optimize the query with SP or [**MySQL views**](https://www.guru99.com/views.html)*

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a separate relational table called say, `codes`, where you store the id of the related item in the table `inpatient_ipd_vw` and store the `master_code`, being for example, PFMD, as well as the specific code `hospcode`, PFMD{whatever}, should you need it. Then you can do a join with the `inpatient_ipd_w` table and the `codes` table and use regular wheres which will be significantly faster.

Or, easier:

You can add a column in the table `inpatient_ipd_w` called, for example, `master_code` where you store just the start values of the code `hospcode` e.g. PFMD. You can still keep your specific code field `hospcode`. Then you can just do your query using wheres on `master_code`; this will also be significantly faster, and with a simple script you can populate this column rather easily.

---

On top of that you can use CodeIgniter's query caching to speed everything up. Just make sure that whenever an item is modified, added, or deleted you need to delete the accompanied cache file otherwise changes won't be reflected. Query caching often makes your pages load just as fast a static one would, however use at your own risk, you have to know what you are doing.

Comment: I will try this one. Thank you @Alex :)

Comment: (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where Start2 <> 'MI' and Start2 <> 'PD' and Start2 <> 'PF' and casecode = casecodex) as ACTUALHOSP

Comment: Now I have this one but still it takes 30+ seconds to load. :(

Comment: has it improved any? maybe try doing a get_compiled_select to get the full statement and then run it on phpmyadmin to see if it is any faster. try to eliminate all possibilities. you have like 10 different wheres that definitely don't help, as well as a group_by and like 5 different sums... its like the trinity of slowness in a query. you might have to do stored procedures or caching of some kind.